# In vertical blinds, what is the part called that attaches a slat to the rail?

Tags: repair, replacement, blinds

A few days ago, our dog clipped our vertical blinds, taking one slat down.  I was going to re-attach the single fallen slat to the mounting clip that's connected to the rail, but a small gear inside that clip-like-unit must have come out.  I know this because when I re-attach the slat to the clip, it no longer rotates when I turn the blinds.

I apologize for the vague description, I am unsure what all of these parts are called.

As I cannot find that small piece, I need to purchase a replacement part.  I have started searching for this, but I have no idea what this part is called.   What is this part called?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps its a Vertical Blind Carrier?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/10-QTY-Vertical-Carrier-Attaching/dp/B00JI5D4RO/ref=pd_bxgy_hg_img_z

Comment: @sborsher  that seems to an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that was indeed the part I needed.     It was listed as:

> Vertical Blind Repair Carrier Stem and Gear for Attaching Slats

[image]